# Hold down a key for a while and couldn't remove pending key down/key press messages after releasing the key

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question about `PeekMessage` method usage in **C#**.

Here is my case: I hold down a key (Enter or F8, for example) for a while. While the key is held down, the code keeps doing something.

I was trying to create the code to stop doing those things immediately after releasing the key, but I had some difficulty.

What I did was to overwrite `ProcessKeyPreview` method to figure out if a key was held down for a while to generate multiple key down and/or key press events. If that's the case, once the key is released, I was using  `PeekMessage` to remove the following pending messages and hoped it would stop processing those accumulated key down/key press messages, but it didn't work.

1. WM_CHAR
2. WM_SYSCHAR
3. WM_IME_CHAR
4. WM_KEYDOWN
5. WM_SYSKEYDOWN

Any help would be appreciated.

Some code snippet is listed as follows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool PeekMessage([In, Out] ref MSG msg, HandleRef hwnd, int msgMin, int msgMax, int remove);

//----------------------------------------------
// Define the PeekMessage API call
//----------------------------------------------
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MSG
{
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public int message;
    public IntPtr wParam;
    public IntPtr lParam;
    public int time;
    public int pt_x;
    public int pt_y;
}

/// <summary> 
/// Trap any keypress before child controls get hold of them
/// </summary>
/// <param name="m">Windows message</param>
/// <returns>True if the keypress is handled</returns>
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    const int WM_CHAR = 0x102;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
    const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
    const int WM_SYSCHAR = 0x106;
    const int WM_IME_CHAR = 0x286;

    KeyEventArgs e = null;

    if ((m.Msg != WM_CHAR) && (m.Msg != WM_SYSCHAR) && (m.Msg != WM_IME_CHAR))
    {
        e = new KeyEventArgs(((Keys)((int)((long)m.WParam))) | ModifierKeys);

        if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYUP) || (m.Msg == WM_SYSKEYUP))
        {
            //If the key is held down for a while to generate multiple WM_KEYDOWN messages
            if (mRepeatCount > 1)
            {                        
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }

            mRepeatCount = 0;
        }

        // Remove any WM_CHAR type messages if supresskeypress is true.
        if (e.SuppressKeyPress)
        {
            this.RemovePendingMessages(WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYDOWN);
            this.RemovePendingMessages(WM_SYSKEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN);
            this.RemovePendingMessages(WM_CHAR, WM_CHAR);
            this.RemovePendingMessages(WM_SYSCHAR, WM_SYSCHAR);
            this.RemovePendingMessages(WM_IME_CHAR, WM_IME_CHAR);
        }

        if (e.Handled)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
}

private void RemovePendingMessages(int msgMin, int msgMax)
{
    if (!this.IsDisposed)
    {
        MSG msg = new MSG();
        IntPtr handle = this.Handle;
        while (PeekMessage(ref msg, new HandleRef(this, handle), msgMin, msgMax, 1))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem without the code. Please post what you have done so far.

Comment: PeekMessage seems awfully complex if you only need to be notified of keyboard events. Since you're in C#, why not simply use Control.KeyUp and Control KeyDown?

Comment: There are too many controls and it's not feasible to add the logic in all of their KeyUp and KeyDown event handlers. That's why I chose to use ProcessKeyPreview per the suggestion on some other threads in stackoverflow.

Comment: But you don't have to use seperate event handlers for each control - you can use the same for each, if needed.

Comment: Understood. But it's the existing code I needed to change, not the brand new code. I had to modify many files using this way, which is not feasible.

Comment: I know this is a very late response, but could Form.Keypreview do the trick here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx